# transpose /unpivot solution for SQL in teradata

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata, transpose, unpivot

Let's say we have data as below

```
city     |    grp1|    grp2|    grp3|    grp4|token1|token2|token3|token4
('mumbai','111111','222222','333333','444444' ,1001,  2001,  3001, 4001),
('pune','555555','666666','777777','888888',   1002,  2002,  3002,  4002);
```

Note that

```
grp1 is related to token1
grp2 is related to token2
grp3 is related to token3
grp4 is related to token4
```

I am looking for the below output: (8 rows)

```
city,grp_consolidated,token_cons
mumbai,111111,1001 | 
mumbai,222222,2001 | 
mumbai,333333,3001 |
mumbai,444444,4001 |
pune,555555,1002 | 
pune,666666,2002 |
pune,777777,3002 | 
pune,888888,4002 |
```

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table(
  city VARCHAR(8),
  grp1 VARCHAR(8),
  grp2 VARCHAR(8),
  grp3 VARCHAR(8),
  grp4 VARCHAR(8),
  token1 DECIMAL(31,18),
  token2 DECIMAL(31,18),
  token3 DECIMAL(31,18),
  token4 DECIMAL(31,18)
);
INSERT INTO sample_table
VALUES
('mumbai','111111','222222','333333','444444',1001,2001,3001,4001),
('pune','555555','666666','777777','888888',1002,2002,3002,4002);
```

Note: Please do not provide solutions using CASE / UNION/UNION ALL

Comment: If you do not want a solution that includes Case/union/union all, perhaps an explanation why would be pertinent. Stack over flow exists to answer questions and if the best answer to your question includes those, I'd expect to get them. If there is a specific reason you do not want those types of answers included, i'd recommend sharing. Thank you for providing ddl and example data!

Answer (score 0):

Simple task for UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT city, grp, token
FROM sample_table 
UNPIVOT 
 (
   (grp, token) FOR x IN (
                           (grp1, token1)
                          ,(grp2, token2)
                          ,(grp3, token3)
                          ,(grp4, token4)
                         )
 ) AS unpvt
;
```